Cant append an object array to file in Python
I'm using file = open("EncodeFile.p",'ab') to append my array to file already exist and have data also. But when I print the value studentNames and It does'nt change value.
I'm using 'ab' to append array to file already exist.
encodeListKnown = findEncoding(folderList)
encodeListKnownWithIds = [encodeListKnown,studentNames]
print(studentNames)

file = open("EncodeFile.p",'ab')
pickle.dump(encodeListKnownWithIds,file)
file.close()

This printed my studentNames ['BeCam']. And then I called file again to check my file.
file = open('EncodeFile.p', 'rb')
encodeListKnownWithIds = pickle.load(file)
file.close()
encodeListKnown, studentNames = encodeListKnownWithIds
print(studentNames)

This returned a value I create before by using 'wb'
['NguyenDucManh', 'testing', 'testing2']
I can't uderstand the where's the promblem, the file "EncodeFile.p" was changed to new numpy array but the value such as encodeListKnown or studentNames i printed didn't changed.
I also tried
with open("EncodeFile.p", "ab+") as file:
        file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        pickle.dump(encodeListKnownWithIds,file)
        file.close()

but still not working

for more information
encodeListKnownWithIds after pickle.dump(encodeListKnownWithIds,file)
return array[0,02 0,32 ...], ['BeCam']
encodeListKnownWithIds before encodeListKnownWithIds = pickle.load(file)
return array[0,02 0,52 ...], ['NguyenDucManh', 'testing', 'testing2']

Appending to the file doesn't append to the array. It adds a second array to the file. The first array is unchanged. If you want to append to the array, load from the file into an array, append to the array, then overwrite the file with the updated array.

thanks, problem is fixed. I used with open('EncodeFile.p', 'rb') as file: to get array and then used extend to add new value, finally I used with open("EncodeFile.p",'wb') as file: to reup the file
